# GWT push button blue border behaviour

Tags: gwt

Does anybody can tell me where that blue border that appears after you push a PushButton comes from?

I really want to override that behaviour, don't know where or how though

UPDATE:

the effect I'm talking about turns out to be blue on Safari, it goes orange on Chrome and no effect on Mozilla

it occurs when the button has been pressed once, best way to explain it is the http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the "focus ring" that appear around any element when it's focused?

You can tweak it using the `outline` set of CSS properties: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#dynamic-outlines
But please note that it's bad practice (re. accessibility) to completely remove it, as you'd remove any indication of whether the button is focused or not, and incidentally, which element is focused, if any.

Comment: awesome thats the one, I don't want to remove it, I just want all browsers to show the same color, as mentioned before every browser is throwing a different one

Comment: Yes, but people are used to the outline of their browser. I'm using Chrome and I know it uses a yellow outline, so if you make it a small dotted line as in, say, IE, I might not notice it, or simply not get used to it; and if it annoys me, then maybe I'll switch and no longer use your app –if that's a possibility–). Coding for the web is not about making it look the same everywhere (that's so 20th century!) but to make it look and behave the way users expect it, i.e. not changing their browser's default behavior/l'n'f too much)

Comment: Well, GWT is putting outlines on push buttons on the Mac, and that’s totally not the way Mac users expect it (and it’s downright ugly).

Comment: It's not "GWT", it's its "clean" theme. I, for one, never use GWT built-in themes. That being said, a) most devs of the GWT team are using macs, and b) _aqua_ buttons are so ugly on the web…

Answer (score 0):

This behavior should be defined in the appropriate stylesheet. If you check GWT sources that would be in /trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/theme/standard/public/gwt/standard/standard.css. It's also defined in other themes.

What you should do is define your own styles

```
.my-PushButton
{
    border                      :   1px solid #666;
    padding                     :   0 10px;
}
.my-PushButton-down-hovering
{
    background-color            :   #aaf;
}
.my-PushButton-up-hovering
{
    background-color            :   #afa;
}
```

And then

```
PushButton btn = new PushButton(...);
widget.setStylePrimaryName("my-PushButton");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you check the UPDATE on top please?, thx for the answer as well